# How to find number of homescreens in android phone

Tags: c#, android, android-uiautomator

I wrote C# code that via adb send command "uiautomator dump"  and search for location of specific icon location, but in case that the icon is not in the current homescreen I swipe for next homescreen to find him and so on.
Is there any way to find how many homescreens exist in the device ?

Answer (score 0):

No. A home screen implementation does not have to offer multiple "screens" at all. Nor does it have to use swipe gestures to move between "screens". All that is part of the internal implementation of a given home screen, and it does not have to be discoverable from outside of the app.

A *specific* home screen implementation might expose that information somehow, but you would want to contact the developers of that home screen to find out.

Comment: And if I need it only for launchers of Samsung, there is away to find it ?

Comment: @DrDobunBrogly: Samsung probably has several launcher implementations, given their breadth of devices. For details, you would have to contact Samsung.